# Deleting items from a CoreData relationship using .onDelete in a list

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

My app has a detail view that displays a list of items in a relationship to the detailed attribute. I am trying to find a way to delete these items without using `.sorted()` because the order of the items may be indeterminate (this is because the Comparable implementation is indeterminate. Also needs to be fixed but not the subject of this question). My current code is this:

```
extension MyItem {
    var myData: Set<MyData> {
        get { myData_ as? Set<MyData> ?? [] }
        set { myData_ = newValue as NSSet }
    }

extension MyData: Comparable {
    public static func < (lhs: MyData, rhs: MyData) -> Bool {
        // not guaranteed to be determinate sort algorithm
    }
}
```

currently implemented as:

```
struct MyItemDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @ObservedObject var myItem: MyItem

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(myItem.myData.sorted(), id: \.self { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            .onDelete(deleteMyData)
        }
    }

    private func deleteMyData(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { myItem.myData.sorted()[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
            PersistenceController.shared.saveContext()
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the 2 instances of `.sorted()` may not yield the same results. Although this definitely needs to be fixed, I would like to develop a method to guard against this in the future. The results of swiping to delete will delete a different row than the row that was swiped.

Is it better to use `myItem.RemoveFromMyData_` in the `.map`? If so, how to do so without changing the order but making sure the types match up?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not make myData an array and have it sorted from the start?

Comment: Is `self` really unique? *not guaranteed to be determinate sort algorithm* seems to be true @JoakimDanielson `sorted()` called on a Set returns an array.

Comment: @vadian yes of course but if it is a (sorted) array from the start then OP wouldn’t need to worry about the order being different, that was my point.

Comment: Clearly a better sort algorithm is part of the story, but the question is really about the most robust way of deleting items that are part of a relationship of the detail view’s ObservedObject.

Comment: `ForEach` requires that the items can be identified uniquely. If they are unique you get the robustness. When using `\.self` **you** are responsible for making sure that the items are unique.